# Can I use V and W sound interchangeably sometimes?

Tags: pronunciation, conversation

I understand the difference between **v** and **w**, but when speaking I have difficulty in using the proper **v** and **w** sound. And I don’t see any significant differences when I mix **v** and **w** sound in speaking. 
So is it ok to mix up **v** and **w** in normal speaking?

Comment: No, not in most standard dialects, if you care about the quality of your accent.

Answer (score 2):

> when speaking I have difficulty in using the proper **v** and **w** sound

That happens to many foreigners, you are not alone. However, if you want to speak **proper** English, you must practice to use v and w **properly**.

The reverse is equally true: native English people find it difficult to learn the (special / specific) sounds of other languages.

In some cases, mixing the v and w sounds in English changes the meaning of the word.

Examples:

- [vine](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vine) vs. [wine](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/wine);
- [vest](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/vest) vs. [west](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/west);

and the list may continue.

Answer (score 0):

I think that usually English speakers are open minded for variants as well as dialects and accents. That's what nice in English language. But if we are talking about correctness and accuracy then each letter should pronounced as it should.

Now, why is it important to differentiate between the sound of **v** and **w**? Because sometimes it changes the meaning. For example:

> **V**ine Vs. **W**ine ("I like vine" Vs. "I like wine")

> **V**iper Vs. **W**iper ("It's a viper" Vs. "It's a wiper".)

> **V**eil Vs **w**ail

> **R**oving Vs. **R**owing

> I **w**ish Vs. I **v**ish...

> Vest Vs. West ("It is in the **v**est." Vs. "It is in the **w**est")

> **V**ain Vs. **W**ain ("It's vain" Vs. "It's wain")

> One vs van
> ("This is the **one** that I want" Vs. "That is the **van** that I want".)

Anyway I think it is possible to live with it since it's (changes of v-w) very common in some accents (such as the Indian accent).

Comment: “One” and “van” have different vowel sounds.

Comment: While I agree that "W" and "V" should *always* sound different, these are poor examples.  "Vish" is not a word.  "One" doesn't sound much like "van".  Yes, it's possible to live with it, but it's better to make the effort.

Comment: @user67265 the word "one" has the same pronunciation as 'w'. Once you cannot pronounce w properly you cannot also pronounce 'one' properly. It is the same.

Comment: @andrew "vish" is a verb in English http://www.dictionary.com/browse/vish anyway I added another example.

Comment: @Manifestation_Peculiarity I understand “one” is pronounced with “w”, but the point is even if you use “v” in “one”, you still hear difference between “one” and “van” because they have different *vowel sounds*.

Comment: @Manifestation_Peculiarity  you must love playing Scrabble.  "Vish" is indeed some kind of slang variation of "phish", but it's not something most people would know.

Comment: I had never heard of "vish" before. I had to look it up. It says its etymology dates between 2005-10. I don't think I'll ever use that word.

Comment: Also, "one" and "van" sound nothing alike; "one" sounds like "won".

Comment: I don't see why it should be downvoted